# How to pass a component as a prop in another component in svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have 2 components - ***Slider Component and Button Component***

Following is the ***Button*** component

```
<script>
  export button_type, custom_class, clickHander;
</script>


<button type={button_type} class= "{custom_class} on:click="{clickHandler}"
  <span>{buttonType.button_text}</span>
</button>
```

I am using the above ***Button*** component in ***Slider*** Component

```
<script>
import Button from './file_path'

</script>
<div>
   <h1>I am slider</h1>
   <Button />
</div>
```

My objective is to use this ***Slider*** component in the ***App.svelte (root)*** and pass the props to ***Button*** from ***App.svelte***

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why would you pass an entire component as a prop?

Comment: Dynamic components and layouts come to my mind.

Comment: @chovy: I can reuse the "Slider" component with the "Button" Component on different pages and the "Button" component can be customized within the page in which the "Slider" Component is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare a property which is then spread on the `Button`.

```
<script>
    import Button from './Button.svelte'

    export let buttonProps;
</script>
<div>
   <h1>I am slider</h1>
   <Button {...buttonProps} />
</div>
```

```html
<!-- In App -->
<Slider buttonProps={{ button_text: 'OK', clickHandler: () => alert('!') }} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c3374edf4fa1481f86a5f2b0e0648ca7?version=3.49.0)

You can of course also declare individual properties and pass them on as needed.

Comment: Your answer partially solves the problem. I should have put the question slightly differently. I will post another question now. I would appreciate if you can help